# How to stop an audio of SKSpriteNode after its removed from the scene(Swift)?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction, sknode

Here is my code:

```
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    let backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background.jpeg")
    backgroundImage.size = self.frame.size
    backgroundImage.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    backgroundImage.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(backgroundImage)


    let addBugAction = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock({
        self.addBugsToScene()
    }), SKAction.waitForDuration(1)])
    self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(addBugAction))

}

func addBugsToScene() {

    let bug = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Mos2.gif")
    bug.name = "Mosquito"


    //giving random position to and assigning to bugs
    let randomPoint = gettingRandomPosition(bug.size)
    bug.position = CGPoint(x: randomPoint.x, y: randomPoint.y)
    bug.zPosition = 12



    let blockOFaction = SKAction.runBlock({

        let randomMovingPoint = self.gettingRandomPosition(bug.size)

         let action = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: randomMovingPoint.x, y: randomMovingPoint.y), duration: 2)

        //action.speed = 3.0
        let movePlusSoundAction = SKAction.group([action,SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("MosquitoNoise.wav", waitForCompletion: false)])

        bug.runAction(movePlusSoundAction)

    })
    let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
    bug.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([blockOFaction, waitAction])))


    self.addChild(bug)

}



override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
    {        

   /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if touchedNode.name == "Mosquito"{

            touchedNode.removeAllActions()

            //touchNode.runAction(SKAction.Stop())

            //removing the bug which is tapped
            touchedNode.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}
```

When I touch node(bug), it will be removed from the scene. Here I'm trying to stop the playing audio associated with the bug. But audio continues playing even after node is removed from the scene. How do I stop the audio as soon as the node removed from the scene?

Comment: By the way, using self like that inside of a closure and repeating that action forever, will certainly make your scene to not deinit properly.  Either use capture list (something like `[unowned self]` ), or remove that action before the actual transition to the next scene. Always check if your scene's `deinit` is called properly (do this for every custom class you made).

Comment: @Whirlwind  I didn't know about this.. But will research about it and will implement . Thanks again for helping me to make my code better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[+ playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:) just plays a sound. You don't have control over the sound you are playing (can't pause it, unpause it, stop it etc). There are some people saying you can assign a key to the sound action and stop an action by removing the key. That never worked for me so far (tried it on many iOS versions).

Also, the last iOS version I've tried this trick with action key was 9.1...So, there is a chance and you may try it on 9.3...

Anyways, this is from the docs:

> Use SKAction playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion: only for short
>   incidentals. Use AVAudioPlayer for long running background music. This
>   action is not reversible; the reversed action is identical to the
>   original action.

So, it simply plays the short sound and that's it.

As an alternative, you can use [SKAudioNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAudioNode/) but it is available only on iOS9 and above.

Comment: I implemented using SKAudioNode, and now its working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I coded to get the result.

I added below code in addBugToScene()

```
let mosquitoNoise = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "MosquitoNoise.wav")
    mosquitoNoise.autoplayLooped = true
    mosquitoNoise.runAction(SKAction.changeVolumeTo(0.3, duration: 60))
    bug.addChild(mosquitoNoise)

//changes made here
 let movePlusSoundAction = SKAction.group([action,SKAction.runBlock({

            mosquitoNoise.runAction(SKAction.play())
            })])

        bug.runAction(movePlusSoundAction)

    })


 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if touchedNode.name == "Mosquito"{

            //removes the SKAudioNode so audio will stop
            touchedNode.removeAllChildren()

            //removing the bug which is tapped
            touchedNode.removeFromParent()

        }
```